# I want to make a program to open the current opened file and line in chrome devtools in vscode(maybe webstorm also)

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

How can I go about doing that ? I think it would be lot easier if chrome devtools had a keyboard shortcut to copy the file and line number. That way could get the information easily. So maybe user can copy current file and line number to keyboard and a node program can listen to the clipboard change and thus open the file in vscode or some other IDE

Comment: FWIW You can attach VSCode to your live code in the browser and debug it inside VSCode.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for that. That is very true. I can do that, but still, I wanted to do what I have asked in the ques. because vscode debugger doesn't have all features of chrome devtools.